# How to make TFS build result be "Partially Succeeded" when there are build warnings?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS server 2012 and have CI builds set up on a build server.

Currently, the build result is "Failed" if anything failed to compile, "Partially Succeeded" if there are any unit test failures, and "Succeeded" otherwise.

My problem is that I don't want the result to be "Succeeded" if there are any build warnings, whether they be compiler warnings, Code Analysis warnings , StyleCop warnings, or whatever.

Is there any way to modify the build configuration so that the presence of warnings causes the result to be "Partially Succeeded" instead of "Succeeeded"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below custom activity will set build status to `PartiallySucceeded`:

```
   [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public class Activity : CodeActivity
    {
         protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
         {
              IBuildDetail build = context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();
              build.Status = BuildStatus.PartiallySucceeded;
              build.Save();
         }
    }
```

**Other possible choices include:**

`All`                          All status applies.

`Failed`                       Build failed.

`InProgress`    Build is in progress.

`None`  No status available.

`NotStarted`    Build is not started.

`PartiallySucceeded`    Build is partially succeeded.

`Stopped`   Build is stopped.

`Succeeded` Build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

build is reported as "Partially Succeeded" when the "Test Success" property is set to "False" and "CompilationSuccess"="True". 
So you can add customized activity that check theses properties, add this activity to tour new template of build.

Comment: Treating warnings as errors is not what I want. If I go that route, the entire build will abort if there is a single StyleCop violation. I don't want "Failed", I want "Partially Succeeeded".

Comment: Where those properties (build status and Test Success) defined and how can I set them from my custom activity? Also, how can I determine if there are any warnings?

Comment: You must create activity based on Workflow Foundation, create new library, and integrate activity in your template based on sequential workflow, theses propeties are related to workflow, you can adjust easily by defining binding between your activity and your workflow parent

Comment: I think I know how to make an activity and integrate it into the workflow, but I'm not really sure how the code in the activity can read/set those properties. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Workflow encapsulate activity so activity can access properties of parent, i try this night to code sample